# Why Angular directive don't work if it added in runtime

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I add new directive after button click

```
angular.module('app').directive('fieldTypeString', ['config', function(config){
                                  alert('directive runned');
                  return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: config.some_path
            }
```

Later I add this directive in DOM

```
var row = angular.element('<div class="fields-list-row">');
var dir_scope = $scope.$new(true);
dir_scope.field = field;
var field_directive = angular.element($compile('<field-type-string></field-type-string>')(dir_scope));
row.append(field_directive);
element.append(row);
```

But it doesn't work! Why? If I use angular.module('app').directive in init script then it work:

```
angular.module('app').controler(...).
  service(...).
  directive('fieldTypeString',...)
```

Help me, please.

Comment: templates can be added to the DOM during run phase or the compile phase without issues. They can also be added during the controller function, or the link phase as long as they are explicitly compiled and linked in your directive's link function.

Comment: I don't think there is actually enough information to help here. Maybe put something on jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: It's lazy loading (http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/). I think, it's what I want. `// Registering a directive after app bootstrap
$compileProvider.directive('SomeLazyDirective', function()...`